# Setting time limit for getting requests response with try-except

Tags: python, try-catch, time-limiting

My `Python 3.8` script consumes an external REST API using `requests`, which is sometimes slow. How can I set a time limit to waiting for each response so that it just skips that request and treat that iteration as incomplete, preferably using `try-except`?

Comment: requests.get() takes an optional timeout parameter. See: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request